# How to run Minecraft 1.12.2 on the latest release of raspbian

Tags: pi-3, java, minecraft

I have tried the regular method to installing minecraft 1.12.2, that didn't find `./runOptifine1_12_2.sh: 52: ./runOptifine1_12_2.sh: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/bin/java: not found`

I also tried the debian package from minecraft.net but that couldn't install. I am not sure how to fix any of the issues.

Comment: Are you sure the JDK package is installed? Try: `java -version` ti figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've used the following tutorial:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=243946

This was updated 10/11/2019 and should resolve your java not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Click the applications button on the top l-hand corner and go to games it should show minecraft v alpha. Just click on minecraft.

Comment: -1. The OP wanted the full version of Minecraft, not v0.1.1 alpha.